# Are there no active owners for the spring cloud aws project anymore?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I see no activity within the last couple of months in the project [spring-cloud-aws](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws). No issues get answered, no PRs get reviewed or merged. This is a problem for my team, because we're trying to use this module, as we're heavily relying on spring boot apps and on sqs queues, but there are new features which does not get included into the module anymore, for example list typed message attributes for SNS messages.

One of my colleagues even opened a PR fixing the above issue, but there is no reaction. I do not really know how to raise awareness of this problem within the spring team.

Is the Spring developer team even aware of this issue and just don't care or is it unknown for them? If someone could take ownership of the project, at least for approving PRs, that would be great. I personally, would not really want to write custom implementations for integrating with AWS, or use the raw API without spring.

Comment: Probably not the right forum for this question, but we are aware. Spring Cloud AWS is a community-run project. We are looking for maintainers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suspected that this is not the correct place to answer questions like this, but I could not really find any place to contact spring dev, as I mentioned there are no responses to issues on the particular project. What is the process for finding new maintainers? Can I observe this process somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this sort of thing happens often to OSS. You may want to re-upload this as a derivative so changes can be made by you and the community once more.
This project is under the Apache license so derivatives are perfectly OK.

Comment: Thank you. I don't really think ripping this project from spring would be a good idea, but forking the repo until there are active maintainers again, who can accept changes might worth a try.

Comment: That would make him a maintainer, which we are looking for.